# Access Class Methods by string class name

Tags: c#, .net

**Background:**

I have a string variable called `"object_model"` which could have one of this two values (`"UserImage"`, `"CarImage"`) and using it in my code like this:

```
switch (object_model)
            {
                case "UserImage":
                    { UserImage.Add(img); break; }
                case "CarImage":
                    { CarImage.Add(img); break; }
            }
```

**Question:**

I need to avoid using switch statement and simply do it like this:

```
object_model.add(img)
```

**Note:** I've achieved the same in Ruby on Rails by using `constantize` (i.e `model_object.constantize.add(img)`)

Comment: This setup seems a little strange. Can you give more context about what you are trying to do? Where is `object_model` coming from? What are `UserImage` and `CarImage`? Variables? Static classes?

Comment: @InBetween UserImage and CarImage are Static Classes

Comment: there is a way using interface with IoC container and Strategy pattern, but it will take more then 4 lines of code. And if you not using IoC container you would need to add them (autofac, ninject, e.t.c) 
Might take a look at https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/09/30/design-patterns-and-practices-in-net-the-strategy-pattern/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Type t = Type.GetType(object_model);
MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("Add", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
method.Invoke(null, new object[] { img });
```

Comment: Its not immediately clear that `UserImage` and `CarImage` are in fact static classes. They could be variables too.

Comment: This answer is on the right track, although w.r.t. to what @InBetween said the title does say *Access Object Instance Methods* (I think `Type.GetType("object_model")` should be `Type.GetType(object_model)`)

Comment: Also, `Type.GetType("object_model");` should be `Type.GetType(object_model);`

Comment: @InBetween Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you sanitise `object_model`, otherwise a user might be able to call `Add(object)` on any static class.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that your `object_model` is a string, in that case you could just write an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Add(this string object_model, Img img)
    {
        switch (object_model)
        {
            case "UserImage":
                { UserImage.Add(img); break; }
            case "CarImage":
                { CarImage.Add(img); break; }
        }
    }
}
```

You could use it just as `"blabla".Add(img)`
Danger is that you actually permit such calls for any string, so it's your own responsibility to decide if you should add this model or not.

Since your variable could have only two values it's better to define it as  `Enum` and than extension method could be called on Enum not on string.

Comment: Thanks but I don't need it to only Add() method, I need to use it in any other methods of class

Comment: @MoamenNaanou That's exact what you need, you will have an Add method, that you cold call on any string variable in any other method or class